# when i run show # error space error found if i remove # errors line the show #p error deeper error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

```
Haml::SyntaxError in Recipes#new
Showing /home/shoaib/Documents/Projects/recipe_box/app/views/recipes/_form.html.haml where line #4 raised:

The line was indented 4 levels deeper than the previous line.
Extracted source (around line #4):
2
3
4
5
6
7

 - if @recipe.errors.any?
 #errors
     %p
       = @recipe.errors.count
       Prevented this recipe froms saving
     %ul
```

Comment: Is that your actual code with the actual indentation? If so, then your indentation is, in fact, incorrect. Make sure you're indenting with spaces, not tabs.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please [edit] your question and format the code. As is, it's unreadable and you probably won't get good answers. What really helps is a [mcve]. You may want to take the [tour] of the site.

Answer (score 0):

Add two spaces before `#errors`. Haml indentation is it's base, it defines it's blocks of code instead of using a closing line so you must respect it and you should only only spaces (not tabs) and always the same amount (convention is 2 spaces).